# org.hibernate.HibernateException when migrating from Spring 3 to Spring 4

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am migrating an application from Spring 3 to Spring 4. In particular, I am migrating it to

```
    <spring.version>4.2.9.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <org.springframework.ws.version>3.0.8.RELEASE</org.springframework.ws.version>       
    <hibernate.version>4.3.11.Final</hibernate.version>
```

Here is the original code that worked with Spring 3:

```
public AcmeUserBean loadUserByDn(String userDn) {
    AcmeUserBean result = null;
    Session session = null;
    try {
        session = this.currentSession();

        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

        Query query = session.createQuery(
            "from AcmeUserBean as user where user.distinguishedName = :userDn");
        query.setString("userDn", userDn);
        List objs = query.list();

        if (objs != null && objs.size() > 0) {
            result = (AcmeUserBean) objs.get(0);
        }

        tx.commit();
        session.close();
        return result;
    } finally {
        if (session != null) {
            session.flush();
            session.close();
        }
    }

}
```

With Spring 4, I updated it to:

```
@Transactional
public AcmeUserBean loadUserByDn(String userDn) {
    AcmeUserBean result = null;
    Session session = null;
    try
    {
        session = this.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();

        Query query = session.createQuery(
            "from AcmeUserBean as user where user.distinguishedName = :userDn");
        query.setString("userDn", userDn);
        List objs = query.list();

        if (objs != null && objs.size() > 0) {
            result = (AcmeUserBean) objs.get(0);
        }

        return result;
    } finally {
        if (session != null) {
            session.flush();
            session.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Each line in the method succeeds and `result` is not null at the return line.  However, an exception occurs when the method exits:

> org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not
>   commit Hibernate transaction; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.TransactionException: commit failed

The containing class is a 'Dao' class and is annotated as @Repository.

First of all, is my migration of the code correct?  Second, what is causing the exception and how can I fix it?

Comment: Remove the `try/finally`. Spring is managing the session and you shouldn't interfere with that. But why change the code, if it works with Spring 3, it will still work with Spring 4. I would first upgrade Spring then optimize the code, optimizing the code has nothing to do with the Spring version. .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be because of the session is closed. In methods with Spring managed transaction (`@Transactional`) ,Spring will handle session commit and session close.  If you do `session.close()`, the above error will appear.
comment `session.close()` and try it.

```
@Transactional
public AcmeUserBean loadUserByDn(String userDn) {
    AcmeUserBean result = null;
    Session session = this.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();

        Query query = session.createQuery(
            "from AcmeUserBean as user where user.distinguishedName = :userDn");
        query.setString("userDn", userDn);
        List objs = query.list();

        if (objs != null && objs.size() > 0) {
            result = (AcmeUserBean) objs.get(0);
        }

        return result;
}
```